# Recognize pattern of characters

Tags: regex

I am student in the college and I need some help with recognition pattern of characters: what it will match ? or maybe somebody can explain how does it work ?

**" (k[abc]*p)+ "**

Thank you for any help.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/gD9mM5/1

Comment: if you add an 'e' between the brackets, it matches ' kebap '. Hmm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a vague question as you're basically asking how regular expression work.

First of all I would recommend 'Mastering Regular Expressions' which is a pretty great O'Reily book on regex.

Also, for a regex playground, I really like to use Rubular (http://www.rubular.com/) as a playground, although this is meant for ruby, it can give you a good understanding into general regex expression and comes with a nice quick reference guide.

Taking some time to figure this out yourself will be very helpful, regular expressions are not going away.

In this case, your expression is evaluating everything inside the () as one chunk. So it's looking for a k, then at least one (+) of either abc ([abc]) followed by a p, at least one time (+).

So things like kap, kabcp will match.